# PHP-CLI 5.4 - GOTO Alternative

Tags: php, command-line, goto

I working on an PHP-CLI (PHP 5.4+) application and I got to part where evil [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) is required.

Example:

```
<?PHP

// I use PHP  League CLImate and I load it here
/*
 *
 * Many lines of different code and output
 *
 */

MAIN_MENU:
// Some checks which will affect menu below
$climate->clear();
$climate->white("1. Eat sandwich");
$climate->white("2. Eat apple");
$input = $climate->white()->input('Lets go and:');
$input->accept([1, 2]);
$option = $input->prompt();
switch ($option) {
    case 1:
        // Eat sandwich and show output
        // Show some more output
        // Pause a bit
        GOTO MAIN_MENU;

    case 2:
        // Eat apple and show output
        // Show some more output
        // Pause a bit
        GOTO MAIN_MENU;
}
```

<s>I think that I have reasons to use evil `goto`. Unfortunately `goto` is not exist any more as of PHP 5.3.</s> There is GOTO but is there any alternative way?

<s>I need to use PHP 5.4+ because PHP 5.4 is the oldest supported by [PHPLeague CLImate](https://github.com/thephpleague/climate).</s>
 So, basically, it offers some options to user, user chooses an option, it does the task and then it should go back to main menu.

Comment: Where is the `MAIN_MENU` label?

Comment: Line 10. It was missing, sorry.

Comment: GOTO can be replaced by function calls

Comment: Perfectly solvable using while.

Comment: Well, I forgot about both. :/ An consequence after 12+ hours of coding.

Comment: Uh, `goto` didn't exist **before** PHP5.3 ... this question is completely moot.

Comment: I think this is applicable https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @rdlowrey
I misunderstood http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php
I was though it was exist as of PHP 5 and removed in PHP5.3.
@ MichaelCalkins
I know about that one, it's already available at link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate this behavior with a [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement:

```
while (true) {

    // Some checks which will affect menu below
    $climate->clear();
    $climate->white("1. Eat sandwich");
    $climate->white("2. Eat apple");
    $input = $climate->white()->input('Lets go and:');
    $input->accept([1, 2]);
    switch ($input->prompt()) {
        case 1:
            // Eat sandwich and show output
            // Show some more output
            // Pause a bit
            continue 2;

        case 2:
            // Eat apple and show output
            // Show some more output
            // Pause a bit
            continue 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case `continue 2` could be replaced with just `continue` or `break`, isn't it?

Comment: @Fvu `switch` is considered a looping structure. You need the `continue 2` to continue the `while` loop around it.

Comment: @mureinik `break` would "jump" to the end of the switch block (as would a `continue` without level, and as there's no code between the end of the switch block and the while block, the net effect would be the same.

Comment: @fvu good point. I think that using `continue 2` is a good defensive practice in case you later add something after the `switch`, but I agree - in the current state of the code, the net effect would be the same.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, [goto was **added** in 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php), not removed.

So it works quite fine and is used by many projects (mostly parsers and state-machines).

Comment: Well, I missunderstood the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php
I was hought it existed from PHP 5 to PHP 5.3. However I think that while loop is perfect solution, so GOTO is out of consideration, for now.